# Работа middleware в джанго

Tags: django

Вопрос такой. Разместил сайт на хостинге. В своем коде, в middleware считается количество просмотров и ip-адреса, с которых идут запросы. Вроде бы, простой код и не должно было быть неожиданностей, но в итоге в БД сохраняется только один адрес - 127.0.0.1. Вот код middleware.

class CounterMiddleware:

```
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    remote_address = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    if isinstance(remote_address, (list, tuple)):
        remote_address = remote_address[0]
    if not RemoteAddress.objects.filter(remote_address=remote_address).exists():
        RemoteAddress.objects.create(remote_address=remote_address)
        ob, created = Views.objects.get_or_create()
        ob.views = F('views') + 1
        ob.save()
    else:
        o = RemoteAddress.objects.get(remote_address=remote_address)
        if now() - o.updated > TIMEDELTA:
            ob, created = Views.objects.get_or_create()
            ob.views = F('views') + 1
            ob.save()
        o.updated = now()
        o.save()
    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response
```

Попросил знакомых зайти на сайт, но сохраняется только localhost. Не могу понять почему.

Comment: Читайте в документации хостинга, как у него правильно получать IP-адрес

Comment: Скорее всего, Вы получаете адрес прокси-сервера (Nginx / Apache). Они сохраняют реальный адрес, но в дополнительных заголовках запроса. Например, у Nginx нужно смотреть `X-Forwarded-For`

Comment: Уточните, какой Вы используете хостинг. Настройки прокси-серверов могут отличаться

Comment: Спасибо, видимо, да, так и есть, хостинг beget